# 401 console errors using Angular and Breeze

Tags: angularjs, breeze

As a bit of background - I have created a simple interceptor to handle 401's in angular. All the data in the application is retrieved from the server using breeze.

Below is the 401 interceptor I am using

```
app.factory(serviceId, ['$q', '$location', function ($q, $location) {

        var authInterceptorServiceFactory = {};

        var _responseError = function (rejection) {
            if (rejection.status === 401) {
                $location.path('/login');
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }

        authInterceptorServiceFactory.responseError = _responseError;

        return authInterceptorServiceFactory;
    }]);
```

Whenever I attempt to navigate to a page that requires the user to be authenticated it works as expected and I am redirected to the login page. My console however is littered full of errors and it looks rather unprofessional, is there anyway to get rid of or suppress these errors?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Breeze is doing this. Search *breeze.debug.js* and you'll find no references to the console or a logging component. When a $http call returns anything but a 200, breeze rejects the promise so that layers up the line can decide what to do. In many cases it delegates back to Angular. All of this is evident when you read the breeze code.

I suspect that you need to configure Angular to suppress this console output.

Do update us when you figure it out.